# Ionic Can't save PushToken

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to follow this tutorial https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/ to add push notifications to my app. When the app runs on my phone it crashes without starting. And from chrome inspector I got the following error message. 
[image]

This is my code.
app.module.ts :

```
    const cloudSettings: CloudSettings = {
  'core': {
    'app_id': '5186aaf6'
  },
  'push': {
    'sender_id': '20589804805',
    'pluginConfig': {
      'ios': {
        'badge': true,
        'sound': true
      },
      'android': {
        'iconColor': '#343434'
      }
    }
  }
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    CloudModule.forRoot(cloudSettings)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}]
})
```

app.component.ts

```
export class MyApp {
  rootPage = HomePage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, public push: Push) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
    });
    alert("App Started");
    this.push.register().then((t: PushToken) => {
      return this.push.saveToken(t);
    }).then((t: PushToken) => {
      console.log('Token saved:', t.token);
    });

    this.push.rx.notification()
      .subscribe((msg) => {
        alert(msg.title + ': ' + msg.text);
      });
  }
}
```

I am using an android device to test the app. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks..

Comment: from the warnings looks like *none* of the plugins are installed correctly. Did you install plugins with `--save` option

Comment: yes I use save option and packages are included in package.json and config.xml

Comment: does `ionic state reset` work?